# Added reference to System.Data.SQlite.Linq, still get assembly reference missing error

Tags: c#, .net, linq, sqlite, system.data.sqlite

I am trying to use SQlite with Linq and I want to add mappings for my table manually.

To do that, I added reference to my project my going to (right click) References > Add Reference and then  choosing the two .dll files found here:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\System.Data.SQLite\2010\bin`

`System.Data.SQLite.dll and System.Data.SQLite.Linq.dll`

I changed my platform target to x86 by going to Project Properties and choosing x86 under Build tab.

I want to be able to use the Mapping attributes like I would from `System.Data.Linq.Mappings`

But when I compile, I get the following error:

`Error  1   The type or namespace name 'Linq' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Data.SQLite' (are you missing an assembly reference?)`

I did use the two statements at the top of my file:
`using System.Data.SQLite;`

`using System.Data.SQLite.Linq`

I am using Visual Studio 2012.

I have been stuck on this for 3 days. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a problem like this the other day, but with a different library. Mine had to do with namespace conflicts. Did you try deleting either System.Data.SqlLite and leaving System.data.SqlLite.linq and vice versa?

Comment: Still no luck. Any other ideas?

Comment: My problem was namespaces so there must be some conflict

Comment: When I view System.Data.Sqlite.Linq in object browser it comes up as empty whereas System.Data.Sqlite does not. Any idea what might be going on with that?

Comment: try making sure all your class names have been fully qualified namespaces ie System.Data.Sqllite.Linq.[SomeClass] since the two libraries have the same namespace there could be some confusion